# shell scripting: `set -u` and `$*`

Tags: shell-script

I found a surprising behavior while playing around with one of my shell scripts. Assume the following snippet:

```
set -u
output()
{
    echo "$*"
}
output
```

I tested this snipped with bash, ksh93, mksh, zsh, dash and pdksh.
All but pdksh works as expected.

Pdksh complains about `*: parameter not set`.

Well, pdksh is (somewhat) right. There are no parameters to `output`, so `$*` is not set.

I worked around it by replacing `$*` with `${*:-}`.

- Is pdksh right, overly  picky or wrong?
- Is the workaround `${*:-}` valid?

---

Update triggered by comments on Schilys answer:

- I'm on Fedora 31, picked up pdksh somewhere, not installed via package manager
- pdksh version is `@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2` - quite old
- Used pdksh just while testing portability of a script.

Comment: Also interesting why the difference to `( set -u; output() { declare -a arr; echo "${arr[*]}"; }; output; )` which gives `arr[*]: unbound variable` => [here is some discussion about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394251/why-are-empty-arrays-treated-as-unset-in-bash)

Comment: The [heirloom shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) (an old version of the Bourne shell) suffers of the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `$*` and `$@` reflect the current arguments (the arg vector) and thus by definition never have the state of being `unset`, so `set -u` must not affect these variables.

In former times, more shells had this kind of problems and your `${*:-}` workaround was not uncommon.

`pdksh` is known to be buggy and it is no longer actively maintained as an own project, so do not expect bugs to be fixed.

`mksh` (the shell from `MirBSD`) is a fixed and actively maintained variant of `pdksh` that is portable and thus usable on many platforms. Thorsten Glaser is doing a great job here...

Comment: `pdksh` _is_ actively maintained, on OpenBSD, and on OpenBSD the code behaves as expected.

Comment: Do you get a generally compilable variant from that source? Is that OpenBSD `pdksh` a potential downstream from MirBSD?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know the details, but `mksh` (which I've never used) documents its own history as "a successor to `pdksh`". The `mksh` shell is not _upstream_ of OpenBSD `pdksh`. I'd be slightly surprised if OpenBSD's `pdksh` compiles cleanly on e.g. Linux (or SunOS if you will), so it may not be of interest here, unless the user in the question runs OpenBSD (which would be an _old_ release in that case).

Comment: So you seem to understand that your original statement is questionable since the original `pdksh` was intended to be a portable piece of software. Mentioning `BSD*'s` in such a context is generally a problem, since private software on a typical `BSD` usually does not compile on a `POSIX` platform.

Comment: But we don't know what Unix the user is using.

Comment: I agree with you on the arg vector. Anyway: Is `${*:-}` a correct construct?

Comment: @Ralf this was in use in formert times when more shells had that problem.

Comment: @Kusalananda We definitely know that he is not using `OpenBSD`, since he observes the problem.

Comment: We know that he's not using a _recent release_ of OpenBSD, yes.

Comment: mksh, oksh, posh are just forks of pdksh (itself based on the Forsyth shell). mksh and oksh do track each other to some extent in that changes in one are sometimes reflected in the other. Something similar happens for the sh of FreeBSD and NetBSD (based on ash instead of pdksh). mksh is portable though so I agree with schily that it makes it more of the natural evolution of pdksh. (@Kusalananda)

Comment: I'd say `${1+"$@"}` and `"${1+$*}"` are more idiomatic. In any case, using `$*` or `$@` unquoted makes little sense. See also https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/

Comment: I wouldn't say that `mksh` is "fixed" (all software have bugs), just that it has fixed many of the bugs of pdksh. That particular one was fixed in version R39.